# Magento! A Call to a DAL Server on or before or around OnePageController or Success.php

Tags: php, magento, activerecord, checkout, cart

#### Ok so I have customized the Mage_Checkout_OnepageController

1. I need to be able to connect to a DAL server and save certain things there. I got everything correct. It's RESTful, so I am sending a POST request. It's works all just fine. But I need to send one more thing aside from quoteData, item details etc. that one more thing is the *magento orderId*.
2. I understand that Magento hasn't created the order Id on **Mage_Checkout_OnepageController** yet, it generates it on **Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success**. I have my own **X_Request_Block_Checkout_Success**. Within this file the following code;

   ```
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
   $orderInfo['orderId'] = $order->getIncrementId();
   ```

But in this Success.php, this time I can't get the data I get in **Mage_Checkout_OnepageController**, namely the followings; (any quoteData, shipping address etc)

```
$jobSiteAddress = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->toArray();
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

and some other things, I hope you get the idea.

#### Big Question

So my question; Is there a way to get *magento orderId* and all cart data either in **Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success** or in my **Mage_Checkout_OnepageController**

I tried

In My OnePageController I have;

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
```

I tried getting the magento order id after this line but no luck

do let me know If I didn't explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

SO, to be clear, you need to have an orderId before magento really generates it ?
Can you explain more why it's needed ? Why don't you do this call after the order is really generated (magento sales/order events can clearly do this)

Anyways,  it seems hard to me to get the next orderId (you can't be sure of the next increment_id if 10 customers orders simultaneously, and i don't think you want to create an order if the user haven't pay already) but you should be able to determine the next OrderIncrementId as it's linked to customer history...